# Unable to cast object of type error in lambda expression (CsvHelper)

Tags: c#, linq-expressions, csvhelper

Using CsvHelper and ClassMap to map object model to output.
Trying to dynamically generate the mapping via lambda expressions.
Have so far:

```
public class BaseClassMap<TClass> : ClassMap<TClass> where TClass : class
{
    public BaseClassMap(List<string> columns)
    {
        var index = 0;
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(TClass).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            index = columns.IndexOf(prop.Name);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                var columnAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == typeof(ColumnAttribute)) as ColumnAttribute;

                var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TClass), "x");
                var memberExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, prop.Name);
                var memberExpressionConversion = Expression.Convert(memberExpression, typeof(object));
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TClass, object>>(memberExpressionConversion, parameterExpression);
                Map<object>(lambda).Index(index).Name(columnAttribute != null ? columnAttribute.Name : prop.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting:

> Unable to cast object of type `CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberMap 2[KXL_CDMS_svc.Data.Entities.ExpTempApplication.TempEnvPermitTrackingCdms,System.String]` to type `CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberMap 2[KXL_CDMS_svc.Data.Entities.ExpTempApplication.TempEnvPermitTrackingCdms,System.Object]`.

at

```
Map<object>(lambda).Index(index).Name(GetTitle(columnAttribute != null ? columnAttribute.Name : prop.Name));
```

New to lambda expressions.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a different overload of the `Map` method.

```cs
public class BaseClassMap<TClass> : ClassMap<TClass> where TClass : class
{
    public BaseClassMap(List<string> columns)
    {
        var index = 0;
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(TClass).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            index = columns.IndexOf(prop.Name);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                var columnAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == typeof(ColumnAttribute)) as ColumnAttribute;

                Map(typeof(TClass), prop).Name(columnAttribute != null ? columnAttribute.Name : prop.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnks will try!